# Registation email taking too long to send to new users

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a registration script where users can be created on my website.  I am really struggling with emails being sent with a huge delay, meaning the registration link has expired before any users get their email.

```
 <?php
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST['n_register']))
    {
        $mail = trim($db->EscapeString($_POST['reg_mail']));
        $mail_re = trim($db->EscapeString($_POST['reg_mail_re']));
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z_\\-][\\w\\.\\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/i", $mail))
        {
                    $errorMsg = $langBase->get('home-08');
                }
                elseif ($mail !== $mail_re)
                {
                    $errorMsg = $langBase->get('home-09');
                }
                elseif ($db->GetNumRows($db->Query("SELECT id FROM `[users]` WHERE `email`='".$mail."' LIMIT 1")) > 0)
                {
                    $errorMsg = $langBase->get('home-10');
                }
                elseif ($db->GetNumRows($db->Query("SELECT id FROM `[users]` WHERE `IP_regged_with`='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' LIMIT 1")) > 0)
                {
                    $errorMsg = $langBase->get('home-11');
                }
                elseif ($db->GetNumRows($db->Query("SELECT id FROM `temporary` WHERE `playerid`='".$mail."' AND `active`='1' AND `area`='register' AND `time_added`+`expires`>'".time()."' LIMIT 1")) > 0)
                {
                    $errorMsg = 'You should already have an activation email from us.  Check the spam box, if not, contact us.';
                }
                elseif (!isset($_POST['acc_tos']))
                {
                    $errorMsg = $langBase->get('home-12');
                }
                else
                {
                    $extra = array(
                        'mail' => $mail,
                        'enlist' => isset($_GET['e']) ? $db->EscapeString($_GET['e']) : $ref_id,
                        'affid' => isset($_GET['aff']) ? $db->EscapeString($_GET['aff']) : $aff_id
                    );
                    $enlist_id = isset($_GET['e']) ? $db->EscapeString($_GET['e']) : $ref_id;

                    $tempID = substr(sha1(uniqid(rand())), 0, 6);
                    $db->Query("INSERT INTO `temporary` (`id`, `playerid`, `area`, `expires`, `time_added`, `extra`)VALUES('".$tempID."', '".$mail."', 'register', '10000', '".time()."', '".serialize($extra)."')");

                    mail($mail, $admin_config['game_name']['value'].' » Game Regsitration', 'href="'.$config['base_url'].'?side=signup&amp;step=2&amp;v='.$tempID.'">'.$config['base_url'].'?side=signup&amp;step=2&amp;v='.$tempID.'</a>
                                            <br />
                                            This link will remain active until <b>'.View::Time(time()+10000, true).''.$admin_config['game_name']['value'].'
```

Could anyone see any issues here?  Maybe the email text needs to be longer?  There is obviously some HTML in the middle of this script.

Thanks!

Comment: what mail server are you using?

Comment: @ultrajohn I'm afraid I'm a complete newbie and am unsure, I will find out and get back to you.  The script was purchased

Comment: anyway, you can always check if the code gets executed to completion in a timely manner whenever you try to send an email, and if it does, then I think the problem lies in the mail server that you are using.